# JsonSchema Validation not throwing error for different property NAME

Tags: python, json, validation, jsonschema, json-schema-validator

This is my json schema

```
{
"title":"Sl",
"description":"A user request json",
"type":"object",
"properties":{
    "FRETL":{
    "id": "#FRETL",
    "type": "array",
    "items":{
        "type": "object",
        "properties":{
            "instances":{
            "description":"ThE Instance(Comma Separated Allowed)",
            "type":"string",
            "minLength": 1
            },
            "ID":{
            "description":"The ID of the Instance",
            "type":"string",
            "minLength": 1
            },
            "Number":{
                "description":"Mention The Number associated",
                "type":"string"
                },
            "EndDate":{
                "type":"string",
                "format": "date",
                "pattern": "(((19|20)([2468][048]|[13579][26]|0[48])|2000)[/-]02[/-]29|((19|20)[0-9]{2}[/-](0[469]|11)[/-](0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|30)|(19|20)[0-9]{2}[/-](0[13578]|1[02])[/-](0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])|(19|20)[0-9]{2}[/-]02[/-](0[1-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-8])))",
                "description": "We expect yyyy-MM-dd"
                },
            "StartDate":{
                "type":"string",
                "format": "date",
                "pattern": "(((19|20)([2468][048]|[13579][26]|0[48])|2000)[/-]02[/-]29|((19|20)[0-9]{2}[/-](0[469]|11)[/-](0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|30)|(19|20)[0-9]{2}[/-](0[13578]|1[02])[/-](0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])|(19|20)[0-9]{2}[/-]02[/-](0[1-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-8])))",
                "description": "We expect yyyy-MM-dd"
                },
            "Comments":{
                "type":"string",
                "description":"Justification"
            }
        },
        "if":{
            "properties":{
                "instances":{
                    "enum": [
                        "*"
                    ]
                }
            }
        },
        "then":{
            "properties":{
                "ID":{
                    "description": "please enter the AssetID",
                    "minLength": 1
                }
            }
        },
        "required":[
            "instances",
            "ID"
        ]
        },
    "ABTRIC":{
    "id": "#ABTRIC",
    "type": "array",
    "items":{
        "type": "object",
        "properties":{
            "instances":{
            "description":"ThE Instance(Comma Separated Allowed)",
            "type":"string",
            "minLength": 1
            },
            "ID":{
            "description":"The ID of the Instance",
            "type":"string",
            "minLength": 1
            },
            "Number":{
                "description":"Mention The Number associated",
                "type":"string"
                },
            "EndDate":{
                "type":"string",
                "format": "date",
                "pattern": "(((19|20)([2468][048]|[13579][26]|0[48])|2000)[/-]02[/-]29|((19|20)[0-9]{2}[/-](0[469]|11)[/-](0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|30)|(19|20)[0-9]{2}[/-](0[13578]|1[02])[/-](0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])|(19|20)[0-9]{2}[/-]02[/-](0[1-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-8])))",
                "description": "We expect yyyy-MM-dd"
                },
            "StartDate":{
                "type":"string",
                "format": "date",
                "pattern": "(((19|20)([2468][048]|[13579][26]|0[48])|2000)[/-]02[/-]29|((19|20)[0-9]{2}[/-](0[469]|11)[/-](0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|30)|(19|20)[0-9]{2}[/-](0[13578]|1[02])[/-](0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])|(19|20)[0-9]{2}[/-]02[/-](0[1-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-8])))",
                "description": "We expect yyyy-MM-dd"
                },
            "Comments":{
                "type":"string",
                "description":"Justification"
            }
        },
        "if":{
            "properties":{
                "instances":{
                    "enum": [
                        "*"
                    ]
                }
            }
        },
        "then":{
            "properties":{
                "ID":{
                    "description": "please enter the AssetID",
                    "minLength": 1
                }
            }
        },
        "required":[
            "instances",
            "ID"
        ]
        }
    }
```

And this is the json I am providing.

```
 {
"FRETL":
[
    {
        "instances": "i-123",
        "AssetID": "1231",
        "Number": "12312",
        "StartDate": "2021/12/12", 
        "EndDate": "2021/12/12", 
        "Justification": "Testing Example"
    }
]
```

}

If I work on this and run the python validator, it will work fine and as expected and as I change the name of FRETL to ABTRIC, the JSON says its still valid and it functions according to the whatever rules I have mentioned in the schema.  But if I change the property name to something else in my JSON input other than the 2 mentioned above(FRETL and ABTRIC) , it will still mark it as valid. I want to make sure it fails if JSON input doesn't consist either ABTRIC or FRETL.

Answer (score 0):

figured it . have to use oneOf

```
"oneOf": [
    { "required": ["FRETL"] },
    { "required": ["ABTRIC"] },
    { "required": ["ABCD"] }
]
```